# Array-instance of class

Tags: java, arrays, instantiation

I found an instantiation wich I do not understand how works.
The instantiation looks like this:

```
public static Class instance[] = new Class[arraySize];
```

If my guessing is right, the instance is an array?
How will this work?

Comment: It creates an array of Class references ("pointers" to Class objects), with `arraySize` number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

This declares an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) of [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) objects references. It is [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1200681/391161) to the other syntax of `[]` after the type.

You would access it just like a normal array:

```
 instance[0] = ...
 instance[1] = ...
```

Comment: can you provide a link so I can read more about it please?

Comment: @KickButtowski, I added a link.

Comment: is it like int[] instance = new int[90] ?

Comment: Ahh, sweet! That is actually something I have wondered in a long time if it's possible!

Comment: @OleKristianMøller-Hansen - No difference whatsoever from creating an array of String, say.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Class instance[] = new Class[arraySize];
```

`public` is the access modifier. This one means that this variable is visible in your entire project
`static` means that this variable is a "class" field it means that it belongs to the entire class and you can access it by `ClassName.nameOfTheVariable` or if you are accessing it from inside of class it is declared you could use just `nameOfTheVariable`.

`Class` in this context is a type and you should treat is as a type of object

`[]` means that this is an array you could also write `Class[]`

`=` is assignment operator

`new` is the word that annunciates that there will be memory allocation and constructor invokation after it

After new there is initialization of array of `arraySize` length.

Comment: Good point:  Java allows the declarations `ClassName[] instanceName` and `ClassName instanceName[]` to be used interchangeably -- both mean an array of object references to `ClassName` objects.

Comment: @Yoda ..Nice answer. I wonder why this answer was never upvoted!!